# Remove submit.x and submit.y but retain other values in URL

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, submit

With my PHP form, I want to pass one value to the URL, but remove submit.x and submit.y. Here's my form:

```
<form action="booking.php" method="get">    
<input type="image" value="access" class="rollbtn" src="../images/book-btn.gif" alt="Book" name="submit" />
</form>
```

I want the URL to display booking.php?submit=access - but omit the x and y coordinates that result from the type="image". If I add `onsubmit="this.submit();return false;"` it strips everything. Is there a way to do this, or should I just use type="submit" and style the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
<button type="submit"><img src="../images/book-btn.gif" alt="Book" /></button>
```

and then use appropriate CSS to remove the button element's default styling such as borders.

Comment: Just remember that in IE6/IE7 you will get this garbage on the URL: submit=&lt;img%20src="../images/book-btn.gif"%20alt="Book"%20/&gt;
(this was fixed in IE8 for the record)

Comment: NickFitz, your code has an Empty tag notation. Pick one or the other. :)

Comment: @epascarello: it's HTML 5, where that is valid HTML markup - cutting edge ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You have a few of options.

1. Input type submit with src of an image;
2. Input type submit with CSS background image; or
3. Image submit that submits with Javascript;

Image submits are meant so you can get the coordinates of where was clicked. It might matter on image maps.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar need, I solved it using jQuery doing something like this:

```
<script src="where_you_have_jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$('#my_form').submit(function(){
   $('#submit_img').attr('disabled',true); 
});
</script>
```

Your submit image has to have "submit_img" (in this case) as its id attribute, for this to work. And your form id="my_form".

Comment: It almost worked for me, only that the 'submit' was not getting called no matter what. However, the basic idea of disabling the submit-image worked for me, when I wrote the code on 'onClick'.